# How can I proof: Figure-Eight Knot is 5-colorable?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am learning Knot Theory recently. So I am doing some hand calculation for to find *p-color* for a Knot. So my current understanding says that **A given Knot can be p-colorable if and only if the Knot can be split into a matrix M and det(M) follows p/det(M)**

[Here is a Figure-8 Knot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91OAv.png)

From there I made a matrix:
$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 &-1 &2 &0 \\ 0 &-1 &-1 &2 \\ -1 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 & -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now I am trying to calculate its determinant and I got $18$, But it shouldn't happen cause Figure-8 will be then 3 and 6 colorable, but 6 colorable is absurd, as $p$ should be prime number.

**So I need help about how can I proof 5-colorability for Figure-8 Knot? Is my understanding is incorrect?**

Update: I solved it and have been able to calculated determinant 5. My mistake was to forgot to remove 1 column and 1 row to calculate the det.

Comment: $p$ doesn't have to be prime for $p$-colorability.  I'm not sure what you mean by "det(M) follows p/det(M)"; maybe "det(M) divides p"?  By the way, I encourage you to write an answer to your question about why the figure-eight knot is 5-colorable.

Comment: Also, I'd expect the determinant to be $0$ if you forget to remove a row and column. Maybe check this?  (The point of removing a row and column is to throw out all the constant $p$-colorings, which always exist, hence the determinant of the original matrix should be $0$.)  A more robust way to prove the figure-eight knot is 5-colorable is to come up with an explicit 5-coloring, which I suggest you try finding -- it doesn't take so much work.

Comment: yeah "p divides by det(M)". 

I am learning recently, can you please explain this line- **The point of removing a row and column is to throw out all the constant p-colorings** a bit? 

And do you mean color  KNOT with 5 different color pencils by this line- A more robust way to prove the figure-eight knot is 5-colorable is to come up with an explicit 5-coloring

Comment: It's called a "coloring" but the "colors" are the numbers $0,\dots,p-1$ modulo $p$.  Could you share what reference you're using to learn about $p$-colorings?

Comment: The determinant of the matrix is 0. No idea how you calculated either 18 or 5.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ (A cheap way to check it is that $(1,1,1,1)$ is a solution to $Ax=0$, so the matrix isn't invertible. The subspace generated by this vector corresponds to all the constant colorings.)

Comment: @KyleMiller I am following this lecture notes by [Anthony Bosman](http://www.anthonybosman.com/lectures.html).

Comment: Then what I was suggesting is to use the definition of p-colorability on page 3 of the handout to construct a linear system of equations for the figure-eight knot and then solve it modulo 5.  A nontrivial solution to this homogeneous system is an explicit p-coloring. (You can also try guess-and-check.)  The whole determinant thing (the theorem following the definition) is mainly useful to figure out all possible values of p such that the knot has a p-coloring.

Comment: @KyleMiller let me check. Thank you for your suggestions.  btw I found [this tool] (https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio) developed by you, amazing